# What does Z_m*/<2> means?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

What is this notation?
I think Z_m*  is a group whose number is i \in Z_m s.t. GCD(i,m)=1 and <2> is a cyclic group

for example m=1023, the order of <2> is 10 since 1024=1 mod 1023
I cannot understand the  slash */*
What is this?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{Z_m}^{*}/\langle 2\rangle$?

Comment: The slash indicates a [*quotient group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group)

Comment: @BabakS.  Yes. thanks

Comment: But in the case m=1023, what are quotient groups??

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916886/how-to-find-the-quotient-group-z-1023-langle-2-rangle).

Answer (score 1):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/m)^*$ has order $\phi(m)$, so $G=(\mathbb{Z}/1023)^*$ has order $600$. It is given by $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^*\times (\mathbb{Z}/11)^* \times (\mathbb{Z}/31)^*\cong C_2\times C_{10}\times C_{30}$. 
Determine the subgroup $U$ generated by $2$ in $G$. By Lagrange, the oder of $U$ is a divisor of $600$. Then determine the quotient group $G/U$ (the "slash").

Remark: I write $\mathbb{Z}/m$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_m$, to avoid confusion with $p$-adic integers, for $m=p$.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a lot going on in your question.  We start with $\mathbb{Z}_m$, which is also written as $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/m$, and $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$.  You can think of this as the set $\mathbb{Z}_m = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, m - 1\}$ with addition and multiplication defined modulo $m$.  As you've undoubtedly observed, multiplication behaves somewhat strangely.  For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, we have $9 \times 5 = 0$, meaning that two non-zero elements can multiply to zero!  Elements like this are called zero-divisors.  On the other hand, we also have $7 \times 13 = 1$, meaning that both $7$ and $13$ are invertible.  A straightforward argument shows that zero-divisors don't have inverses.  It's also easy to show that the product of two invertible elements is also invertible.

The notation $(\mathbb{Z}_m)^{\times}$ is used for the set of all (multiplicatively) invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.  A little work shows that $(\mathbb{Z}_{15})^{\times} = \{1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14\}$.  In fact, an element $k \in \mathbb{Z}_m$ is invertible precisely if ${\rm gcd}(k,m) = 1$; in other words, $k$ is invertible if it is relatively prime to $m$. (Exercise: Show that if ${\rm gcd}(k,m) > 1$, then $k$ is a zero-divisor.)  But $(\mathbb{Z}_m)^{\times}$ is more than just a set, it's a group!  We call it the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Oh, and since the Euler $\varphi$-function counts the number of positive integers that are relatively prime to (and less than) its input argument, we have: $|(\mathbb{Z}_m)^{\times}| = \varphi(m)$.

Two key facts about $\varphi$:

1. If ${\rm gcd}(a,b) = 1$, then $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.
2. If $p$ is prime, then $\varphi(p) = p - 1$.

These facts imply, for example, that $|(\mathbb{Z}_{15})^{\times}| = 8$ and $|(\mathbb{Z}_{1023})^{\times}| = 600$.

In your example, the notation $\langle 2 \rangle$ denotes the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}_{1023})^{\times}$ generated (multiplicatively) by the element $2$.  So: $\langle 2 \rangle = \{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 \}$.

The answer to your final question is a bit more involved, but $(\mathbb{Z}_{1023})^{\times}/\langle 2 \rangle$ is the quotient group formed from the cosets of $\langle 2 \rangle$.  One such coset is $3\langle 2 \rangle = \{ 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 384, 513, 768 \}$.  Since $|\langle 2 \rangle| = 10$, the quotient group has $60$ elements (each coset has $10$ elements and the parent group has $600$ elements.)

So, the quotient group is an abelian group of order $60$.  How many such groups are there? (Hint: Not many!)

Comment: Wow! $11\langle 2 \rangle =\{11, 22, 44, 88, 176, 352, 704,385, 770, 517 \}$ is also

Comment: I wanna ask you about $3\langle 2 \rangle$. Does this *"3"*  come from $i \notin \mathbb{Z}_{1023}^*$??